# Unable to retrieve value from MySQL database

Tags: php, html, sql, database, select

I am using the following PHP code to retrieve the "Location" field from the database in my server, but am getting the error shown below when I run the PHP.

My PHP file:

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","naveen","naveen123","naveen_z");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 'Location' FROM `map_details` ");
print_r($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My database structure:

[image: Database structure]

I am getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in location.php on line 12
```

Now, I'm receiving this:

```
{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":n‌​ull} –
```

Comment: Observation: Don't mix and match identifier quotes. Use `\`` consistently (or, better, only quote when required). `'` should not be used for identifiers because it's actually an ANSI SQL string quote :(

Comment: can u make that php in correct format becoz am getting following null values now it showing all values as null {"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":n‌​ull} –

Comment: $result refers to the *entire* result, not a specific row. It says "there were no rows" (`"num_rows":null`) so the map_details table is most likely empty. Anyway, that's a *different* (and unrelated) problem - post a *new* question as appropriate (but first validate or disprove my previous assertion).

Comment: no check this image  of that table http://tinypic.com/r/2vxjfps/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using quotes instead of backticks,so you are selecting a string.If its not a reserved word you can remove them altogether.

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Location FROM `map_details`")
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use msqli_fetch_array() on the results of the query.

EG: return mysqli_fetch_array($result);

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing quotes on your query:

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 'Location' FROM `map_details`");
```

what's funny is that stackoverflows syntax highlighting caught it!

Also, unless you are trying to select the literal value 'Location' from your table, you want different quotes (either backticks or remove them altogether)

Comment: oooops..my mistake,...now its working but  the $result printing like  "mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 9 [type] => 0 ) "how do i get the reults in JSON

Comment: well, your result is an object, you can call json_encode on the object, and that will convert all public variables into json format.

Comment: it showing all values as null   {"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}